# Render google map in wordpress, based on address custom field

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

I have a wordpress site with a large number of pages, each page represent a physical location. Now for each page I would like to display a google map based on the address. I know I can do this by installing for instance the Geo Mashup plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/geo-mashup/ but that requires (I believe) that I manually, for every post, create a location based on the address and add a shortcode to the post/page that results in a google map. This is a LOT of work for this site with hundreds of locations.

I would like to be able to

> A: Create an "address-custom-field"
>   for each post programmatically.
>  
>   B: In
>   a page template use that custom field
>   to render a google map.

A is easy, but B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to consider using the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/).

The following example may help you getting started. All you would need to do is to change the JavaScript variable `yourAddress` with the address of the location feature in your page. "If A is easy", that should be quite straight-forward.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps API Demo</title> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body onunload="GUnload()"> 

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    var yourAddress = 'London, UK';

    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
       var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
       geocoder.getLocations(yourAddress, function (locations) {         
          if (locations.Placemark)
          {
             var north = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.north;
             var south = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.south;
             var east  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.east;
             var west  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.west;

             var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(south, west), 
                                            new GLatLng(north, east));

             var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

             map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
          }
       });
    }
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

The above example would render a map like the one below:

[Render google map in wordpress, based on address custom field http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/7267/london.jpg](http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/7267/london.jpg)

The map will not show if the [Google Client-side Geocoder](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding) cannot retreive the coordinates from the address.

Comment: Thanks, that is perfect. I noticed that I have to add my Google Maps API key as a get parameter to the javascript call. (key=<mykey>)

Comment: @windyjonas: If you use the latest version of the Maps API (v3), you won't need a key.

Answer (score 1):

This is now obsolete Google removed services for v2.

Use something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you use the address in your example?